# Map is not taking up 100% of column

Tags: html, css

My map is not taking up 100% of my right column. I want it to take up about 45% of the page on the right-side, however, based on the screenshot, it is not even close. Any thoughts on how I can rectify?

Here is the HTML

```
   <div class="column right">
            <div class="column right">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
html {
   height: 100%;
   padding-left: 20px;
}

#map {
   width: 100%;
   float: right;
   height: 600px; 
}


.column {
   padding: 10px;
 }
 
 .left {
   width: 60%;
   float:left
 }

 .right {
   width: 40%;
   float: right;

 }
 
 
 .container {
   float:right;
}

.form-group {
   display: flex;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first div takes 40% of the page and the second takes 40% of the first div, this coupled with the padding provided by the class 'column' gives the map a width of < 16% of the page.
If you really need two div tags make sure only one uses 'column right'